# Camel first experience

Tags: apache-camel

I'm very new with Apache Camel. I can't get the simplest Camel example working. Here is the code:

```Camel
public class CamelFE {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    CamelContext cc = new DefaultCamelContext();
    cc.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Go!");
        from("file://Users/Foo/Desktop/IN")
        .to("file://Users/Foo/Desktop/OUT");

    });
  }
  cc.start();
  cc.stop();
}
```

Both directories exists, in the `from` one there is one simple file, `helo.txt`. The route starts and `Go!` message is displayed but no file was moved to the `to` directory. What am I missing?

Edit:
this is the console output.

`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4j: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details
Go!`

Comment: Remove the `stop()` call, this might be preventing the route from being able to pick up the file. Does the log output say the Apache Camel Context was started?

Comment: Hello. I remove the stop() line but result is the same. I can't see anything about Apache Camel Context. I update the question to show the console output.

Comment: So did you see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details?

Comment: This isn't even valid Java. RouteBuilder needs to have a configure method.

Comment: Do you have any logging implementation (log4j, slf4j) included in your classpath? Without any logging output it will be difficult to tell where the problem is. The context might be failing to be created for some reason.

Comment: @Ray thankyou I updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Windows, since you have references to `Users/.../Desktop`. If that's the case, your file syntax is slightly off. Rather than `file://Users/Foo/Desktop`, you should have `file:///Users/Foo/Desktop`.

You also need to allow enough time for the processing to occur before the application terminates. You might add a `Thread.sleep`. Note that in a web application, this wouldn't be an issue as the app stays running.

```java
public class CamelFE {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext cc = new DefaultCamelContext();
        cc.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder()
        {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Go!");
                from("file:///Users/Foo/Desktop/IN").to("file:///Users/Foo/Desktop/OUT");
            }
        });

        cc.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        cc.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html