# Camel 2nd experience

Tags: apache-camel, stdout

After my succesfull

[Camel first experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998659/camel-first-experience/26999821#26999821)

 I ran into another issue: I can't get my `Processor` to work. Here is the code:

```
public class CamelFE {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    CamelContext cc = new DefaultCamelContext();
    cc.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Go!");
        from("file:///Users/Foo/Desktop/IN")
        .process(new Processor() {
          @Override
          public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("file: "+((File)arg0.getIn().getBody()).getAbsolutePath());
          }
        })
        .to("file:///Users/Foo/Desktop/OUT");
      });
    }
    cc.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    cc.stop();
}
```

I can't get why the processor's message never appear in `stdout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the absolute filename and file contents:

```
  from("file:///Users/Foo/Desktop/IN")
    .process(new Processor() {
      @Override
      public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
        String filename = arg0.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileAbsolutePath", String.class);
        System.out.println("file: " + filename);

        String contents = arg0.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        System.out.println("contents: " + contents);
      }
    })
    .to("file:///Users/Foo/Desktop/OUT");
```

Comment: Hello. Why my implementations doen't work? I don't get any error in return.

Comment: Because the File consumer doesn't automatically convert the payload to the `File` class. The payload of the exchange is the actual contents of the file, which can be converted to `String` or `byte[]` using Camel's built-in converters. I think the reason you aren't getting any errors is because you don't have a logging implementation like log4j or logback...I don't know if Camel will print to `stdout`.

Comment: I can see errors on stdout by having changed the original code this way: 
`public void configure() throws Exception {
 System.out.println("Go!");
 onException(Throwable.class)
    .handled(true)
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
 public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("error.");
     ((Exception) arg0.getProperty("CamelExceptionCaught", Exception.class)).printStackTrace();
 }
    });
...`

Comment: That may allow you to see errors when they happen, but Camel prints a lot of debug statements during context creation, and when it passes messages through that would be extremely useful to see, like WARN statements when something is not configured optimally and it may not throw an exception. It might make your debugging go a lot faster. :)